# Forcing Gridview to display x number of rows including empty rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Is it possible to force gridview to display x number of rows even if the data is less than x rows? With the difference being made up with empty rows, of course.

I found this page: http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.ca/2008/03/how-to-force-force-x-number-of-rows-in.html while trying to google the issue but there's not much explanation on how to use the presented solution.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does what I was looking to do:

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
DataRow dr1;
dt1.Columns.Add("ProjectID");
dt1.Columns.Add("ProjectName");
dt1.Columns.Add("Country");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     dr1 = dt1.NewRow();
     dr1["ProjectID"] = dr1["ProjectName"] = dr1["Country"] = "";
     dt1.Rows.Add(dr1);
}
dt1.AcceptChanges();
ProjectListGridView.DataSource = dt1;
ProjectListGridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Before binding your DataSource to your GirdView, I would check the number of rows returned and add empty rows to your data source.

So let's say you want always 10 rows Visible:

```
var myDataSource = GetDataSource();
if(myDataSource.Count() < MIN_NUMBER_OF_ROWS)
{
    myDataSource.AddRange(GetEmptyRows(MIN_NUMBER_OF_ROWS - myDataSource.Count()));
}
myGridView.DataSource = myDataSource;
```

And then `GetEmptyRows(int numberOfRowsNeeded)` returns the number of empty rows you need.

EDIT: Let's say your source is of type `MyCustomGridRow` with attribute `isValid`. You can then intercept each row on data binding and according to the `isValid` attribute, modify the appearance of your `GridViewRow` (Custom message, colspan, ...).

```
protected virtual void myGridView_OnRowDataBound(GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
     {
         MyCustomGridRow customRow = (MyCustomGridRow)(e.Item.DataItem);

         if (!customRow.isValid)
         {
             int colCount = myGridView.Columns.Count;
             e.Item.Cells.Clear();
             Label lblEmptyMessage = new Label
             {
                 Text = "Custom message for eempty rows.",
                 CssClass = "ErrLabels"
             };
             TableCell newCell = new TableCell
             {
                 ColumnSpan = colCount
             };
             newCell.Controls.Add((Control)lblEmptyMessage);
             e.Item.Cells.Add(newCell);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Is getemptyrows some sort of custom method to create empty rows?

Comment: Yes indeed...so you can customize those rows at the same time and add a "Empty row" message. (Make sure the `GetEmptyRows` method returns the same type as `GetDataSource`)

Comment: Okay... but the problem is how do I create these empty rows? That's kind of my original question.